# Making Rails tests aware of Rack middleware outside Rails's internal chain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, integration, integration-testing, rack

**Context**: an application uses a piece of Rack middleware that **must** be setup in config.ru, rather than Rails's internal Middleware chain. This is for reasons not relevant to this question.

**Question**: how do I make my tests (functional and integration) aware of this middleware?

I'll ellaborate with an example. Let's create a pristine Rails 3 app, using [rack-rewrite](https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite) for illustration purposes.

```
# /config/initializers/example.rb
Rails.application.middleware.insert 0, 'Rack::Rewrite' do
 r301 '/so', 'http://stackoverflow.com'
end

# /test/integration/the_test.rb
require 'test_helper'

class TheTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
 test "redirect from /so to http://stackoverflow.com" do
   get '/so'
   assert_redirected_to 'http://stackoverflow.com'
 end
end
```

If you run the above test, all is good, and with the browser you can confirm that visiting the path `/so` will redirect you to StackOverflow indeed.

Cool, let's now set this up outside Rails then. Remove the file `/config/initializers/example.rb` described above, and change `config.ru` to the following:

```
# /config.ru
require ::File.expand_path('../config/environment',  __FILE__)

map '/so' do
  run Rack::Rewrite do
    r301 '', 'http://stackoverflow.com'
  end
end

map '/' do
  run Deleteme::Application
end
```

Now, the test will stop working. The functionality does work, as evidenced if you visit `/so` with your browser. It's only that the tests are not aware of that Rack setup.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

(Thanks Dan Croak for setting me on the right track. This answer completes what he said).

## Short answer

Can't be done for functional tests.

For integration tests, add the following to your test_helper.rb:

```
ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest.app = Rack::Builder.new do
  eval File.read(Rails.root.join('config.ru'))
end
```

## Long answer

**Functional tests** are just unit tests run against controllers. When you say, for example `get :index`, you are not resolving a route. Instead, this is a shorthand for calling the `index` method, with a request environment that includes a mention to the HTTP method being GET.

Therefore, it makes sense that your Rack stack does not influence functional tests.

**Integration tests** are a different matter. You are testing your full stack there, so you will want to test your Rack middlewares too. Only problem is that, by default, these tests only see the middlewares that you add using Rails's own API.

But I say "by default" because Rails offers a way to change what Rack stack will be tested. By default, integration tests call `Rails.application` for their requests. You can change this to anything that suits your needs.

By using the code above, we use `Rack::Builder` create an ad-hoc Rack application. Inside the block, you can put any code that you would normally put inside a `config.ru` file. To avoid code duplication, `eval` loads our `config.ru` file. Now our integration tests will load exactly the same application that our app servers expose.

Comment: How can I extended this for RSpec?

Comment: If you are using Capybara and want to test in your feature specs, you can similarly do Capybara.app = Rack::Builder.new do
      eval File.read(Rails.root.join('config.ru'))
    end

Comment: I've tried Agustin's solution for RSpec and I can verify that it works. Thanks.

Comment: @JasonSwett how did you apply this to Rspec? Would be appreciated for help here

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is that `ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest` uses your `Rails.application` as its Rack app for the test.

So, if you can wrap that `Rack::Rewrite` rule into some Rack middleware, you should be able to override the Rack app you're testing in your test with:

```
ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest.app = MyRewriteMiddleware
```