# Rspec test for GZIPed response

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, gzip

I recently enabled GZIP on my Rails 4 app following this [Thoughtbot blog post](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/content-compression-with-rack-deflater) and I also have added `use Rack::Deflater` to my config.ru file as suggested by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13877091/4139179). My Rails app seems to be serving compressed content, but when I test for it using RSpec the test fails because `response.headers['Content-Encoding']` is nil.

Here is my application.rb:

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Turn on GZIP compression
    config.middleware.use Rack::Deflater
  end
end
```

Here is my spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe GeneralController, type: :controller, focus: true do
    it "a visitor has a browser that supports compression" do
        ['deflate', 'gzip', 'deflate,gzip', 'gzip,deflate'].each do |compression_method|
            get 'about', {}, {'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING' => compression_method }
            binding.pry
            expect(response.headers['Content-Encoding']).to be
        end
    end

    it "a visitor's browser does not support compression" do
        get 'about'
        expect(response.headers['Content-Encoding']).to_not be
    end
end
```

When I run `curl --head -H "Accept-Encoding: gzip" http://localhost:3000/` I get the following output:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Ua-Compatible: chrome=1
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Etag: "f7e364f21dbb81b9580cd39e308a7c15"
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
X-Request-Id: 3f018f27-40ab-4a87-a836-67fdd6bd5b6e
X-Runtime: 0.067748
Server: WEBrick/1.3.1 (Ruby/2.0.0/2014-02-24)
```

When I load the site and look at the Network tab of the inspector I can see that the response size is smaller than before, but my test still fails. I'm not sure if I'm missing a step here with my test or if there is an issue with my implementation of `Rack::Deflater`.

Answer (score 2):

As @andy-waite pointed, RSpec controller specs are not aware of middleware, but that's why, since RSpec 2.6 we have [request specs](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-6/docs/request-specs/request-spec).

Request specs are, according to the docs:

> designed to drive behavior through the full stack

Therefore, using RSpec > 2.6 request specs, your code should look like:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe GeneralController, type: :request, focus: true do
  it "a visitor has a browser that supports compression" do
    ['deflate', 'gzip', 'deflate,gzip', 'gzip,deflate'].each do |compression_method|
        get 'about', {}, {'HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING' => compression_method }
        binding.pry
        expect(response.headers['Content-Encoding']).to be
    end
  end

  it "a visitor's browser does not support compression" do
    get 'about'
    expect(response.headers['Content-Encoding']).to_not be
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

RSpec controller specs are wrapped around Rails functional tests, which are not aware of middleware:

[Making Rails tests aware of Rack middleware outside Rails's internal chain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5016690/making-rails-tests-aware-of-rack-middleware-outside-railss-internal-chain)

Comment: I inserted the code that Agustin posted into my rails_helper.rb but that didn't solve my problem.